# JavaScript "call on declare" anonymous functions equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, closures, global, anonymous-function

I have some code that i want to be executed in a PHP script, but i don't want the variable created in this script to be visible otherwhere.

What i would like to do is like we can do using JavaScript :

```
(function() {
    // Do some stuff
})();
```

But i'd like to do this with PHP.

I've imagined the following code :

```
$main = function()
{
    global $main;
    unset($main);

    // Do some stuff
}

$main();
```

BUt it's not supported before PHP 5.3, and i need it to be.

Is there another way to do this with PHP 5.2 ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well i've just thought about another way :
`class Main
{
public static function exec() { }
}
Main::exec();`
Is that a good practice ?

Comment: `eval()`, but you don't want to go there.

Comment: Okay thanks, but i would indeed like to avoid this :P

Comment: js is a pretty functional language, while php is not, so without some weird hacks, I don't think this will be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call_user_func(
    // create_function('$param1, $param2', '
    function($param1, $param2) { 
        // do stuff
    }
    // ')
, "param1", "param2");
```

Use the lines commented out for php < 5.3

But I think many people will agree this is a weird thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) but this is ugly i think.

(I have a bigger problem with your code sample and maybe with your real code: you are using global state which is really bad.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "you are using global state which is really bad.".